# Varnish: Caching OPTIONS/CORS requests

Tags: caching, cors, varnish

As stated in the [documentation](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html), the hash key is calculated based on the `Host` header or `IP` and the `URL` of the request:

```
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (lookup);
}
```

How would a correct cache configuration for `HTTP OPTIONS` look like that obviously has the same `URL`, `Host` or `IP` as the corresponding `HTTP GET` request?

```
curl -H "Origin: https://www.example.com" -I \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
  -X OPTIONS --verbose \
  https://backend.server.example/rest/endpoint
```

Also preferable would be to cache the response respecting the `Origin` header that is also part of the CORS request.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following.

To make sure that `OPTIONS` request method can be cached at all, you will need to to call `return` statement from your `vcl_recv` procedure so that [built-in VCL](https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/blob/4.0/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl)'s `vcl_recv` is not run at all. And make some changes to it:

```cpp
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PRI") {
    /* We do not support SPDY or HTTP/2.0 */
    return (synth(405));
    }
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
      req.method != "HEAD" &&
      req.method != "PUT" &&
      req.method != "POST" &&
      req.method != "TRACE" &&
      req.method != "DELETE") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD" && req.method != "OPTIONS") {
        /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        /* Not cacheable by default */
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.method == "GET" || req.method == "HEAD" || req.method == "OPTIONS") {
        set req.http.x-method = req.method;
    }
    return (hash);
}
sub vcl_backend_fetch {
    set bereq.method = bereq.http.x-method;
}
```

For the cache to be different based on Origin header value, you will put something like this:

```cpp
sub vcl_hash {

    if (req.http.Origin) {
        hash_data(req.http.Origin);
    } 
    # no return here in order to have built-in.vcl do its default behavior of also caching host, URL, etc.
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it seems as if enabling caches for `OPTIONS` requests somehow gets translated to `GET` backend fetches. Because of that, the headers differ when I make the request through varnish compared to directly hitting the backend. Any idea?

Comment: It appears that Varnish would transform request to ```GET``` when you ```return(hash)``` in ```vcl_recv``` ... I'll update answer with the trick to bypass that.